# How to configure Liferay Portlet(in Spring) with Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc, liferay-6

I am trying to develop a portlet in Liferay with database interactions,however i am not sure of how to connect Liferay with Hibernate. The portlet is being developed in spring and i know how to configure spring with Hibernate. Its an annotation based project. Please assist me on this.

Answer (score 1):

Connecting liferay with Hibernate ??? If you are developing portlet application and are planning to use Hibernate for persistance, you can do it the way you do for normal web applications. However you can make use of Liferay Service Builder to do the job for you.
Have a look [Service Builder Liferay](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Service+Builder)

Comment: This should be a comment and not an answer